# Why is the image id null inside the Popup().setHTML from Mapbox markers

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

My problem is fairly simple. I don't understand why the id of my img is null. I'm using mapbox markers.

Here's the code for the marker

```
var marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker({ color: 'green' })
.setLngLat([x, y])

.setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup().setHTML("<h1>Hello World!</h1><img id= 'myImg' style = height = '100%' width = '100%' src = 'somePicture.jpeg' > </img>"))
.addTo(map);
```

I'm pretty sure it is related to how i'm writting the html inside the .setHTML, but honestly I just don't understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the only problem, but you are missing some quotes and your CSS syntax is off:

`.setHTML("<h1>Hello World!</h1><img id= 'myImg' style = height = '100%' width = '100%' src = 'somePicture.jpeg' > </img>"))`

Should be something like:

```js
.setHTML("<h1>Hello World!</h1><img id= 'myImg' style = 'height: 100%; width: 100%;' src = 'somePicture.jpeg' > </img>"))
```